# How can I unit test a web service item in ASP.NET web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, webforms, autocompleteextender

I am trying to build a simple search with asp:Textbox that will have autocomplete powered by Ajax Toolkit AutoCompleteExtender. After hours of searching I found out that the only way to call the servicemethod that actually works is to create a new asmx web service and allow it to be called from a script(simply by uncommenting 1 line of built in code). Since the project requires a high percentage of code coverage (unit tests) I was wondering how can I test this class and method?

Comment: Have you had a look at Selenium?

Comment: Well do you want to Unit Test the UI Code, Unit Test the Service Code or do an Integration Test from UI to Service?

Comment: Also the technologies your using are significantly out of date and one reason they have been obsoleted because their nature makes it difficult to unit test. ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI/Modern UI Framework (Angular, Knockout, etc) is much advised

Comment: Jason,  I am forced to use this technology, so MVC is not an option..I am trying to unit test the service code. Also I have little to no idea why [Inject] attribute of Ninject does not work on my property in this class.